# Is it possible to create a voltage divider without resistors?

Tags: operational-amplifier, piezoelectricity

I'm prototyping a chromatic guitar tuner with an [Arduino DUE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue) and a piezoelectric sensor.

[image: TISchematic]

I was trying to amplify the sensor's signal and connect it to the Arduino's ADC pin. So I referred [TI's SLOA033A](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa033a/sloa033a.pdf).

**That orange box, showing 1/2 Vcc, is my concern.**

I'm using a 9V battery and TI's buck converter module to power the board and the Op Amps.

[image: MySchematic]

I created that 1/2 Vcc using a voltage dividing circuit and a buffer circuit.
I wasn't sure whether the voltage dividing circuit without the buffer can handle this.

In sum, these are my questions;

1. Since the Arduino DUE (MCU: ATSAM3X8EA-AU) cannot take negative voltages as an ADC input, that 1/2 Vcc is used to bias the sensor's signal to 1/2 Vcc, right?
2. As shown in my schematic, is the buffer not needed?
3. Lastly, are there alternative ways to create that 1/2 Vcc without this voltage dividing resistors?
   I was imagining some kind of power IC or circuits that create 1/2 Vcc, but I failed to find one.
   If the voltage dividing circuit is the cheapest way, then looks like I have no choice.

-Regards, David

Comment: Use capacitors. Any impedance will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) That is correct

2) I would want a fairly stiff supply there so would recommend keeping the buffer opamp. Without it your potential divider won't maintain half supply voltage if there is any loading.

3) TI make the tle2426 'rail splitter' IC, which has the same function you want but a minimum voltage input of 4 V. I doubt you would find anything specifically for that function cheaper than a pair of resistors and an opamp.

Answer (score 2):

Using a voltage follower buffer is the preferred way of generating the virtual ground for an op amp.

If you google 'virtual ground', you'll find a whole (excuse the pun) ***slew*** of information about this.

It has nothing to do with the Arduino, and while it is true that the Arduino would not be particularly pleased about a negative voltage on any of its pins, this could not happen with or without the '1/2 VCC' voltage.

Where do you think this negative voltage will come from?  The op amp has 3.3V and ground on its power pins.  That means, at best, it can swing no higher than 3.3V and no lower than ground (and usually it's just 'pretty close' to the power rails at best, not actually reaching them).  So unless you are actually creating a voltage that is below the Arduino's ground potential somehow (like a charge pump, etc.), then there isn't any negative voltage potential it can possibly be exposed to.

No, the reason for the 1/2 Vcc reference voltage is to create a 'virtual ground' for the op amp.  Just for a moment, pretend that ground is no longer ground, and that 1/2 VCC voltage is ground.  Note, this doesn't change anything, because these are all just arbitrary labels and voltages are all just arbitrary values that are relative to some arbitrary potential we've chosen as ground.

So, briefly, let's chose a different potential as ground - our 1/2 VCC potential.

Also, I'm going to pretend our original VCC is 3V, rather than 3.3V, just for simpler numbers.

Now, the opamp is no longer powered by 3V referenced to our old ground.  Our new 'virtual ground', with which we describe all over voltage potentials in reference to, has changed things!  Now our op amp is powered by both a positive and negative power rail, 1.5V and -1.5V.  Its output can slew above and below ground, and good thing - our input signal, being an AC audio one, also swings above and below ground.

Meanwhile, our Arduino is also being powered by 1.5V and -1.5V.  And, in fact, there is no problem with its ADC pin taking in a negative voltage, as long as it stays above the Arduino's ground pin (which is at -1.5V) and below its power pin (1.5V).

Now, remember that this is the same circuit.  Nothing has changed except what we decide to call certain things.

The 1/2 VCC voltage is really a pretend ground, a virtual ground - and by referencing our input signal with respect to this ground, it allows it to swing above and below said ground just like an AC audio signal needs to, without actually ever passing below our true ground (unbeknownst to it - the signal is unaffected).

Or, put another way, that 1/2 VCC is there to bias/shift the INPUT signal.  You're basically taking something that, say, is swinging between 0.5V and -0.5V, and just shifting it upwards by 1/2VCC.  So now it's swinging from 2V to 1V.

Anyway, this virtual ground doesn't need to actually pass much current, but it will still pass a bit, and it won't be symmetric at all times (the same current returning to GND vs VCC).  Thus, a resistor divider will have some error because of this, error that will vary depending on what is going on, making it difficult to correct for.

So instead of doing that, we use a buffer.  The op amp buffer is just a voltage follower, letting the voltage divider only need to drive the op amp's very high impedance input, so it will see almost no load.  That way, the divider voltage will exhibit much less error, while allowing many milliamps to be sourced or sunk (or even amps for some high power buffer/op amp parts) without changing that reference voltage.  It is important to remember that such virtual grounds will need to both sink and source current, so most voltage regulators, whether linear or switching, will not be able to generate a virtual ground.  They can source current, or they can sink it, but not both.  This is why both the 7805 and 7905 (5V and -5V regulators) exist.  One can source, the other can sink.  An op amp voltage follower can sink AND source, making it ideal for this application.

You don't NEED to use a voltage divider, you could use a zener diode, or a voltage reference IC, but only a resistor divider will 'track' the input voltage as it varies, and behave ratiometrically.  But, if you're using an op amp buffer, I don't really view this as 'using a voltage divider' anymore.  You're only using one to create a reference voltage, but it is not responsible for actually generating your virtual ground.  It is simply telling the thing that IS generating it - the op amp - where to maintain the virtual ground relative to VCC.

Answer (score 0):

### First you need to consider design specs.

What is an acceptable error for V+/2 including noise from any source?
   Define a budget for resistor tolerance, noise and load regulation
What is an acceptable quiescent current to generate this voltage?
What is the load current ?
What noise current from any source?
Then what is the resulting error for load current* source impedance?
    This source/load impedance ratio creates the load regulation error.

If you meet the criteria with two x% R's and a noise reduction cap,
   then no buffer or OP Amp or active LDO or Rail splitter IC  is needed.
[image: schematic]